# Common function-as-a-service feature for .NET-Core as Azure AppService and On-Premises

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

We have the challenge of implementing services that can be deployed both in an Azure Cloud (On-Demand) as well as in a local LAN On-Premises scenario. This is fine with .NET-Core, SQL-Server, Redis etc.

What we are missing is a common feature for Functions-as-a-service or WebJobs. Both of these Azure services appear to be cloud-only. Is something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) the most viable approach, or are we missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure Functions Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview) enables you to run Function Apps on premise. Note that it's still in preview though.

Comment: Looks "heavier" than WebJobs though. We're looking for something that "just works" for background processes. Any tips appreciated.